# Iterate Over for an Input File Flag

Tags: bash, loops, unix, iteration, filenames

I am using a software in Unix on a computing cluster, for which I need hundreds of input files for a combinative analysis, which wants each file specified with an -f flag, it is like:

```
software -f file1.ext -f file2.ext -f file3.ext
```

Simple bash loop doesn't work to let it comprehend each file, such as:

```
for i in *ext; do software -f ${i}; done
```

Even simpler way doesn't work, either:

```
software -f *ext
```

Specifying the folder where the files are doesn't work, either:

```
software -f .
```

Even a cooler bash script doesn't work (actually not really different from the simple loop):

```
#/bin/bash
for i in $(ls *.ext | rev | cut -c 5- | rev | uniq)
do
software -f ${i}.ext
done
```

So what I need is a way to make the software recognize all my files in the same input flag by iterating the -f as well I believe. Something like:

```
for i in *ext; for each -f; do software -f ${i}; done
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iteratively build an array with the appropriate options.

```
for f in *ext; do
  opts+=(-f "$f")
done
software "${opts[@]}"
```

Comment: As an aside, the `zsh` glob qualifier `P` is the gold standard: `software *ext(P:-f:)`.

Comment: thanks a lot chepner, (it did work of course :) About your answer, is opts a coding word, or do you mean any additional options of the software I could write there?  I didnt know about building such arrays. And your comment, is there a way to implement zsh into a bash script? Cheers

Comment: `opts` is just short for "options"; it's just meant to be descriptive. Any name will work. I only mentioned how you would do this in `zsh` because it is so concise. `bash` doesn't support glob qualifiers, nor is there a way to simulate the effect.